# Opening multiple explorer.exe windows with different sizes and locations

Tags: vb.net

Im rather new to vb.net and have encountered following issue:

Im trying to open up 5 different folders in 5 different explorer windows. All of them should be opened in a fixed position and with a fixed size.

Lets say Folder1 should be at (5,5) with a size of (100,150)

Folder2 should be at (50,5) with a size of (80,75)

Folder3 should be at (100,5) with a size of (100,50)

Folder4 should be at (150,5) with a size of (35,90)

Folder5 should be at (200,5) with a size of (50,35)

I've found this method online to move ALL instances of explorer.exe to a fixed position and resize it -> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f4effba6-ed9b-4e4d-a163-922fc158fdfd/open-file-explorer-and-change-its-sizelocation?forum=vbgeneral

```
    Sub MoveAllExplorerWindows()
    
            Dim ExplorerFileName As String
    
            For Each ExplorerWindow As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer In New SHDocVw.ShellWindows()
                ExplorerFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ExplorerWindow.FullName).ToLower()
                If ExplorerFileName.ToLowerInvariant() = "explorer" Then
                    ExplorerWindow.Left = 0
                    ExplorerWindow.Top = 0
                    ExplorerWindow.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2
                    ExplorerWindow.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height
                End If
            Next ExplorerWindow
    
        End Sub
```

But I want to have, depending on the actual folder, a different location and size. The code above would resize every explore.exe window and put it in the location (0,0).
Does anyone have any idea how I could change the code or implement something completely new?

Thanks in advance! <3

Comment: You can look at the URL of each window ExplorerWindow.LocationURL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752084(v=vs.85) and base your location/size on that.

Comment: @NathanChampion Thank you so much, your solution worked perfectly!